# Do I need to sign IPA file to get on testflightapp.com?

Tags: ios, ipa

I have MyApp.app/ folder on iphone, and my app works fine on JB phone. But I'd like to try on testflightapp.com, but site is puzzling me. I know I can create simple IPA by copying contents to Payload dir and then zipping it. This will work for JB. But can how to move from this to testflight?

I am not using XCode, I compile from command line on iPhone with clang++. So please do not include answers like "Click that menu in XCode". By the way my company does own macbooks, macminis and apple developer accounts, as well as dozens of ipads and iphones, but this is not part of my question.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to sign the ipa with a Distribution profile for Ad-Hoc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to sign the app with a Development or AdHoc profile.
TestFlight will check for the profile for the UDID's to only allow access to the IPA for device that are in the profile.

TestFlight is not ment for jailbreak development, not even if it is for testing only.

You can easily create your own site for supplying Over the Air installation, you can try the opensource [HockeyKit](http://HockeyKit.net/), which is self hosted alternative to TestFlight.

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor it works perfectly with AdHoc builds. I've been using it with AdHoc build since they started.

Comment: Same here, adhoc is the usual build profile. You do need a valid profile since TestFlightApp has special permission from Apple to make this work.

Comment: @ahwulf testFlight does not have any special permission to make it work. It just Over the Air installation, which is fully documented by Apple. All TestFlight does is check if the UDID of the device is in the profile used to sign the app. You do have to install a special configuration profile to allow the testflight website access to you UDID. But you can easily build something like TestFlight your self. Just look at [HockeyKit](http://HockeyKit.net).

Comment: true, I meant that they follow the rules, always a good thing with Apple